# Mapped Network Drives cannot be removed from MSI Installer

Tags: c#, wpf, network-drive

I am working on a windows application which maps the network drives. We would like to remove the mapped drives on uninstall of this application. I have written a custom action which should remove the drives pre-uninstall( tried on Uninstall override as well). As the installer file is running as system account/admin, it is not removing the drives. The user may uninstall the app using the MSI or from the control panel.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Regards,
Silambarasan

Comment: How about you make a script and run it afterwards ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question doesn't have enough information on what's happening. I would recommend you look at the help article on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).